# Cost of an internal update on 100k records

Tags: postgresql, update

I'm curious about an update that I'm planning to do in `pgsql` and cannot find any topic about this case.

I have to do an internal update on a database with 150k records
`UPDATE "table" SET column2=column1` with both columns already declared.

I cannot figure out the time cost of such an operation. If the new value were external, I would say it could take some time (more than 1 or 2 hours) to update the 150k rows but since this is here strictly internal, I'm wondering if this might not be way faster.

Anyone got experience with this that could be shared?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Submitting one query that updates 150k rows will be a *lot* faster than submitting 150k queries that update one row each, but *only* because of the overhead involved in submitting *any* query.
Each and every time, you send some [SQL] text to the database, which parses that text into something it can work with (a Plan), then executes that Plan, and finally sends you back some sort of result.

> To do a Thing takes a finite amount of time.
> To do the same Thing 150k times takes [at least] 150k times as long.

The one thing you *might* notice is that everything else *stops* while you're doing it!
Updating a row here, a row there and another row over there makes for a nice. "sociable" Application.  Grabbing all 150k rows and doing your own thing with them all?  Not so much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I'm not quite sure to see what you reccomend.

I have exactly the same thought, everything will be stopped and it's not nice. But for how long ? Knowing that I'm asking for an internal copy. Is there a chance for it to finish in less than 10 minutes or is it going to block it for hours.

Comment: My recommendation?  As ever - it depends.  :-)
If your company can accommodate the table being locked for a couple of minutes, then run the update and be done with it.  If you can't, then you have to look at ways of "limiting" the update - you can't use the LIMIT clause directly, but you can find ways of doing something similar.  Search for "UPDATE .. LIMIT".   
As for "how long will it take?", that's what your Test databases are for.  They allow you to try out things like this /before/ hitting the Production database with them.

Comment: My test database does not have as much data which is why I came to ask here.

I know for the limit part but I am a bit blind on the portions to make. 

I guess I will try with sections of 20k. I find it hard to think that a simple copy like this could take forever.

Comment: Agreed.  Unless the fields are /huge/, you should be able to do the whole [150k] table in a minute or so.  
Ideally, you really /should/ have a test set-up (server[s], database[s], etc.) somewhere that /is/ "representative" of Production.  Without this, you're reduced to guessing about things like this.  If you can say "I ran it in Test on 140k records and it took 15 seconds", that gives you huge confidence about doing it "for real".

Comment: Thanks, the fields are just basic timestamps.
I made a job that migrate 25k row that I will trigger manually 6 times.
If it was only going to block it for a minute I could really have gone for the whole table in one time but now I will go with this.
I agree for the test database but nowadays it is not possible to have a copy of production database locally. And an anonymizing system would take some times to create.
I have a local db with test data but with less rows of course. 
And since it is in cloud services having a online test db would cost while issue like this happens rarely.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it in live and it is indeed pretty fast.

Operation was done in a matter of a few seconds. Turned out internal query are quite fast.

Following advice here and some generated by AI. If the field are of the same type there is no need to break it in smaller update for an update of 200 or 300 k

Comment: What does pretty fast mean

Comment: As I said on the following line it's a matter of a few seconds. I didn't record it but when I runed a count 10 sec later to see how many record where updated and it was finish.